# Rewrite rules not working with MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following rules:

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="Images">
        <match url="^images/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Content/images/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Themes">
        <match url="^themes/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Content/themes/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Javascript">
        <match url="^js/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Scripts/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

in system.webServer

However they simply do not work? Am I missing anything? When I run and debug in VS these do not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in the `<rules>` tag right after the `<rewrite>` tag?  For example, like this:

```
<rewrite> 
    <rules> 
        <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" /> 
            <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" /> 
         </rule> 
     </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

Reference: http://paulstack.co.uk/blog/post/IIS-Rewrite-Module-and-MVC3.aspx

Comment: Is your Web.config file in the right directory?  Just wanting to make sure... because that can affect your action's `url=""`.